# observer cms block

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, blocks, cms

I m trying to use a new field in cms block . 
it insert well in database , and i can see it on the grid but , in edit i can t see the new field.
I already did it for the cms page and it works .
i used an observer and not a rewrite like this :

```
    class Upecom_Cmstype_Model_Observer
    {
 public function cmsField(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //get form instance
        $form = $observer->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');

        //add new field
        $fieldset->addField('type_page', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'type_page',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Type Page'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Type Page'),
            'disabled'  => false,
            'readonly' => false,
            'required'  => true,
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('upecom_cmstype/page')->getAvailableTypePages()
        ));
    }
        /**
         *  add the field cms_type in the backoffice
         * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
         *
         */
        public function cmsFieldBlock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {

            //get form instance
            $form = $observer->getForm();
            $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');

            //add new field
            $fieldset->addField('type_block', 'select', array(
                'name'      => 'type_block',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Type Block'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Type Block'),
                'disabled'  => false,
                'readonly' => false,
                'required'  => true,
                'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('upecom_cmstype/block')->getAvailableTypeBlocks()
            ));
        }
    }
```

And my config.xml is :

```
 <global>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_cms_block_edit_form_prepare_form>
                <observers>
                    <upecom_page_edit_form>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Upecom_Cmstype_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cmsFieldBlock</method>
                    </upecom_page_edit_form>
                </observers>

            </adminhtml_cms_block_edit_form_prepare_form>

<adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form>
            <observers>
                <upecom_page_edit_tab_main>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Upecom_Cmstype_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>cmsField</method>
                </upecom_page_edit_tab_main>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form>
```

Where is my mistake ? 
I can see the event adminhtml_cms_block_edit_form_prepare_form in core/mage/adminhtml/block/cms/block/edit/form.php

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **CMS Block** try this event

```
<adminhtml_block_html_before>
    <observers>
        <upecom_page_edit_form>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Upecom_Cmstype_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>cmsFieldBlock</method>
        </upecom_page_edit_form>
    </observers>
</adminhtml_block_html_before>
```

In your **observer** file change to this code

```
public function cmsFieldBlock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/cms_block_edit_form') {
        //get form instance
        $form = $block->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');

        //add new field
        $fieldset->addField('type_block', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'type_block',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Type Block'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Type Block'),
            'disabled'  => false,
            'readonly' => false,
            'required'  => true,
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('upecom_cmstype/block')->getAvailableTypeBlocks()
        ));
    }
}
```